# Trying to link many-to-one in MySQL between two tables

Tags: mysql, join, select

Good day,

I'm taking data from a FileMaker database and using it in MySQL for other purposes. I'm dealing with a database of titles, with author information, the ISBN, Title, Price and so on. The point of this question refers to the fact that the original database maintains six fields for subject codes. Three for the fulfillment system, and three BISAC codes. I've created a separate table which contains all the subject codes and the descriptions. I can have 1 to 6 possible codes in a single title record.

I can figure out how to get a single description from one code, but I can't quite figure out how to get multiple descriptions in a single SELECT. I've created 6 foreign keys Sub1,Sub2,Sub3,BI1,BI2,BI3 all pointing to the one code in the subjects table. The Subjects file has only two fields, the code and the description.

I would think this bit should work:

```
SELECT Titles.ISBN,Titles.Title,Titles.Subject_1, Subjects.Description AS S1.Description, Titles.Subject_2, Subjects.Description AS S2.Description 
FROM Titles
Left JOIN Subjects As S1
ON Titles.Subject_1 = S1.Code<
Left JOIN Subjects As S2
ON Titles.Subject_2 = S2.Code
WHERE Subject_2 <> "";
```

Giving me a syntax error. So how do I reference the one description field for each possible subject? Got to the left join from other google searches, but doesn't seem to make a difference. Still quite new to things SQL so forgive me if I'm really overlooking the obvious. This in MySQL 5.7 under Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

You had it almost right.
But the columns from the joined tables must be onb the left side and not as the alias

```
SELECT 
    Titles.ISBN
    ,Titles.Title
    ,Titles.Subject_1
    , S1.Description Description_subject1 
    , Titles.Subject_2
    , S2.Description  Description_subject2
FROM Titles
Left JOIN Subjects As S1
ON Titles.Subject_1 = S1.Code
Left JOIN Subjects As S2
ON Titles.Subject_2 = S2.Code
WHERE Subject_2 <> "";
```